# How to make responsive left side column in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive

I am using 2 rows (header & footer) 1 column (left side) & 1 main content div layout.

It's rock hard layout.

Now when I fetch data using Ajax the main content div stretch because of data & left bar also needs to be stretch and connect to footer but it doesn't.

In sort I want responsive height of left side bar.

Images are below

[without data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3PRe.png)

[with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAD2t.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using any respnsive framework like Bootstrap..if not put a fixed width for your left and right side div.

Comment: Anyone trying to help will probably need your HTML and CSS.

Comment: i am using rock solid html css :(

Comment: layout link http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp

Comment: Show us your code Or a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or snippet will serve better. We need to know the properties/attributes of your elements.

Comment: You need to provide more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

Example code

```
.header{background:red; display:block; color:#fff; padding:20px}
.container{display:table; width:100%}
.sideBar{background:blue; width:23%; color:#fff; padding:20px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:top;}
.bodyContent{background:yellow; padding:20px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:top;}
@media(max-width:760px){
  .container,.sideBar,.bodyContent{display:block; width:100%; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box}
}
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/gjp0jfkL/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

[Working Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/px7yjeg6/1/)

```
.left-col{display:table-cell;}
.right-col{display:table-cell;}
```

above code help you in height issue.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with height actually because might be you have given auto height on left side or may be both left side and right side. So just Remove `float` and `height` from **left and right section** and add `display: table-cell;  vertical-align: top;` on both.

**[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2tpvg1a/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can give position:relative and height:100% to left side bar and position:absolute to right side content panel and give it spacing from left:250px as left side has width:250px.